# Spring Security Facebook Oauth2 redirects to home page

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I can't redirect the user to the previous page after his basic Facebook authentication. Instead I'm getting redirected to the home page. I'm following the example mentioned in https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

This is my structure:

[image]

SocialController:

```
@RestController
public class SocialController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }

}
```

test.html:

```
<div class="container unauthenticated">
    With Facebook: <a href="login">click here</a>
</div>
<div class="container authenticated" style="display:none">
    Logged in as: <span id="user"></span>
</div>

<script>
 $.get("/user", function(data) {
        console.log("Inside users: " + data);
        $("#user").html(data.userAuthentication.details.name);
        $(".unauthenticated").hide()
        $(".authenticated").show()
    });
</script>
```

Main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class IvanstanevPortfolioApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/audio/**" , "/" ,"/index","/contacts","/about_me","/test")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IvanstanevPortfolioApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Basically i want to retrieve users name from Facebook and stay at the page where he was (test.html). Instead im getting redirected to home page. Spent all day on this, cant find a solution. :\

Comment: Did you try https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login? Spring 5 comes with auto configuration.

Comment: No, but i will read it right now. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @reflexdemon i read the guide but I don't understand how am i going to display users name on HTML. Also what is the point of: 5.3. Custom Authorization Endpoint & 5.4. Custom Token Endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, except that the user needs to return to the same page every time rather than returning to the last page.

You can say that the redirect page is hard-coded...but this may help

- Create a class that implements SignInAdapter from package `org.springframework.social.connect.web`
- This class should `@Override` the signIn method, and this method has to return `String`. **This String represents the redirect resource you want to go to.**
- If you want to redirect to the homepage, you can simply **return `null`** for this method.

  ```
  @Service
  public class FacebookSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {
    @Override
    public String signIn(
          String localUserId,
          Connection<?> connection,
          NativeWebRequest request) {

      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
              new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                      connection.getDisplayName(), null,
                      Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("FACEBOOK_USER"))));

      return "/form";
    }
  }
  ```

Here is a useful guide for more details:
https://www.baeldung.com/facebook-authentication-with-spring-security-and-social